# JSON - result displays in HTML id tag but undefined on return statement

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, json

I am new to JSON and working with return data. In the below example, I am able to assign a value to variable `discount` and then display the value in the `showDiscount` html tag. It correctly taps into my test database and returns the correct value and I am able to apply math to the variable as well. This is seen in the commented out portion near the bottom.

My issues is I want to return the value when I call the function; however, I get `undefined` when calling the function. If I can display the value in an html tag, why is the value suddenly undefined on return?

Help is much appreciated!

```
function codeMatch() {
    if ($('#pCodeEntry').val() == '') {
        alert("Please enter a discount code.");
    } else {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "PROMO.svc/MatchCode",
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: "json",
            data: JSON.stringify({ codeInput: $('#pCodeEntry').val().toLowerCase() })
        }).done(function (json) {
            var json = eval(json);
            json = eval('({"d":' + json.d + '})');
            var discount = 0;
            if (json.d != '') {
                $.each(json.d, function (key, value) {
                    discount = discount + json.d[key]['DISCOUNT'];
                    //return discount;
                });
            } else {
                alert("Not a valid code.");
                //return discount;
            }

            // testing the URL purposes
            //var discountReturn = discount * 5;
            // testing the URL purposes
            //var element1 = document.getElementById("showDiscount");
            //element1.innerHTML = discountReturn; // testing only

            return discount;
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: unrelated to your issue but do you really need to use `eval()` here?

Comment: There certainly is no need for `eval`, he can use jQuery (or the browser function directly) to parse the JSON, and replace that next line with `json = { d: json.d};` (although the whole construct looks suspiciously not useful, to say the least - you already have `json.d`and recreate it? Possibly to get rid of all other properties in `json`?).

Comment: If you're always needing to wait for the response when calling the function, you could set `async: false` on your `$.ajax` config?

Comment: Thanks for the tips. The link DCoder posted looks like it will solve my problem, just need to re-code my solution. As for eval(), you guys are right. I based my code off another internal application but just did a little research and I need to change that up as well. Thanks for your help!